# mp4 generated by moviepy no sound with tweepy

Tags: python, ffmpeg, mp4, tweepy, moviepy

I'm using MoviePy to edit a mp4 file and then Tweepy to tweet out the video.

Here's what I have currently:

```
clip = VideoFileClip("c:/users/.../UNIQUENAME2.mp4").subclip(8) #cut off the first 8 seconds of the clip
clip.write_videofile("c:/users/.../UNIQUENAME2-finished.mp4")
clip.close()
highlightz = TweetMachine()
highlightz.makeAVidTweet('c:/users/.../UNIQUENAME2-finished.mp4','audio test')
```

Here's my TweetMachine:

```
def makeAVidTweet(self,fileLoc,text):
        upload_result = self.api.media_upload(fileLoc)
        time.sleep(120) #wait just in case things are still processing
        media_ids = [upload_result.media_id_string]
        self.api.update_status(status=text, media_ids=media_ids)
```

Currently, the video is cut fine and UNIQUENAME2-finished.mp4 is constructed correctly such that if I open the file on my computer, the video is cut correctly and the sound works. However, the video posted on Twitter has no sound.

I'm assuming it's some sort of issue with how MoviePy makes the mp4 file and Twitter not liking something with the sound settings, but I'm pretty unfamiliar with mp4 stuff and I couldn't find anything about it on the MoviePy or Tweepy docs.

Any tips or thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Stream info from VLC:
Codec: MPEG Audio layer 1/2 (mpga),
Type: Audio,
Channels: Stereo,
Sample Rate: 44100 Hz,
Bits per sample: 32,
Bitrate: 128 kb/s

Comment: What's the audio format in the MP4?

Comment: Here's what VLC gave me: 'Codec: MPEG Audio layer 1/2 (mpga)'

Comment: That's a [27 year old audio codec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-1_Audio_Layer_II), sounds like that could be the issue. I'd suggest trying the AAC/MP4 codec.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

```
 clip.write_videofile("c:/users/.../UNIQUENAME2-finished.mp4",temp_audiofile='temp-audio.m4a', remove_temp=True, codec="libx264", audio_codec="aac")
```

Comment: Awesome, so my suggestion to use AAC worked. Glad that was all it took.